# Vue3 input type number get string value

Tags: vuejs3

Vue3 documentation states that

> The number modifier is applied automatically if the input has
> type="number".

Is there anyway to get the string value instead of number?

```
<input type="number" v-model="orderNumber" />
```

I want orderNumber to be string value. I use input type number because I want to display  appropriate keyboard. I want the string value because orderNumber have leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The live version is here](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstuwjAQ/BXLqhSQUKBCvVBAfYhDe6BV6dGXNFmoaWJb9jqlivLvXTuCBqniZs/Mjmc2afi9MWntgc+4UHOXW2mQOUBvlkLJymiLrLGwbdnW6oolJE1uhcq1csi0LcCuffUBli0YqQbJZHKTDElAZuPOjXzoglCZMkOgG2NzqYxHhj8GFoKraCA4q6Si6zWdZnVW+sD1XiD4Ls6dw/TwFdSgMMXM7gDTOJqi3qCVajcYpiYrNsThYDpiySQZCt6FKGS97BnNWNOcNWrb+ThoQpVefD7i6Kj/Vu7SvdOKNtcEP8FzXRlZgn0xKGk/gpNlYAKXlaX+fo4YWg+jI55/Qv71D753h4AJ/mrBga1B8BPXFe3o1WYNBzqfyEoXviT1BfINnC59yNjJHrwqKHZPF9M+xa9PO3x3qwOCcsdSIWhQtlEvOP0Tjxeq/8WdptM4J1TL2198ndTo)

Pass your `orderNumber` to the `<input>` through the `value` prop. And change it with `input` event with formatting:

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
const orderNumber = ref('005');

</script>

<template>
  <input type="number" min="1" :value="orderNumber" @input="orderNumber = $event.target.value.toString().padStart(3, '0')">
  <div>orderNumber: {{ orderNumber }}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" v-model="orderNumber" @input="orderNumber = $event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0+/, '')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use the toString() method
- whenever you need to use orderNumber, simply access it as a
  string by calling orderNumber.toString().

Comment: It will remove leading zeros

Comment: bind  input value to the orderNumber string property using v-model. The @input event listener is used to update orderNumber by removing non-digit characters (/\D/g) and replacing any leading zeros (replace(/^0+/, '')).

Comment: I guess you know the length of leading zeroes. Then you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart